# I want to hide a Picture in Picture icon that comes in upper right corner of video player in swift 4 iOS

Tags: swift, jwplayer

I am using JWPlayer to code for Picture in Picture.

```
self.jwPlayer?.playerView.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
```

im using above property to enable Picture in Picture mode. but when im setting that property to false, still im getting Picture in Picture icon. I want to hide that icon.